# Open file in Append mode in a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, file, append

I have a question,

I have a class that extends BroadcastReceiver in Android. In that class I want to open a file in append mode but if I do this

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(file));
```

Eclipse, says that "The method openFileInput(String) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"

Anyone know how can I do this?

edit: I'm adding more code in order to get a better view of the problem

```
public class ServicioLlamada extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Call c = new Call(Integer.valueOf(number), date, length, TYPE_CALL);
        saveFile(c,context);
    }

    private void saveFile(Llamadas l, Context context) {
        String file = "callList.bin";
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(file,Activity.MODE_APPEND));
        file.write(l);
        file.flush();
        file.close();
     }
```

Comment: Please, put more code of the operation. specially, openFileInput(String) line

Comment: it's quite strange since both `openFileInput(String file)` and `openFileInput(String file, int mode)` are legit and both signatures exist since API v.1. Please add your code with `file` declared

Comment: Hello @a.ras2002...have you found any solution for this..Even I am trying to open a file in a class extending broadcast receiver. same error in this line.. `FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");` _cannot resolve this method_